# Error cast varchar as decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server 2008:

```
select ID,CAST(replace(SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),1,8)+'.'+SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),9,7),',','.')AS DECIMAL (16,7)),    
from T1
```

This is returning cast error.

To find where is the problem I tried the following:

```
select ID,SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),1,8)+'.'+SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),9,7),
isnumeric(SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),1,8)+'.'+SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),9,7))    
from T1
where isnumeric(SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),1,8)+'.'+SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),9,7))<>1
```

But it returns 0 rows, then I guess that all the values are feasible to cast them to decimal but when I run the first query it fails.

Am I missunderstanding something that creates the problem?

P.D: Value is varchar datatype.

Comment: Have you tried finding the actual row that fails in the first query?

Comment: Provide sample data. What is the datatype of `value`? Also provide what is the error that was thrown?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, it is what I try to do with the second query as I explained above

Comment: You can run `select ID, replace(SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),1,8)+'.'+SUBSTRING(LTRIM([value]),9,7),',','.'),    
from T1` and check if the value printed in the 2nd column is a valid decimal

Comment: OK; sorry, I wrote a bad question in my previous comment. Have you identified the row that fails the first query?

Comment: Also, and I hope you're aware of this but it bears mentioning. You should never store numeric data in a text column, precisely because of the problems you're now having. If you are tackling an import problem then unless you're forking out to BCP to import you should tackle the numeric parsing and conversion in the import software, not after you've stored it in the database.

Comment: @KMoussa Yes, there is a lot of rows so to spot it faster I used the second query that is supposed to return the rows that are no valid numbers, between them decimal type.

Comment: @Maik right, but I believe you missed the `replace` from your 2nd query?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen don't worry! The second query has returned 0 rows, so it seems that all are valid numbers. As you say in the other comment it shouldn't we done in this way. But it is a hot fixing before redo all the process and tables...

Comment: You can reduce the number of rows to try in order to try to identify the first bad row by doing `SELECT TOP x ...`, also you should probably add a `ORDER BY` so that the query is stable, then when you find an `x` that fails just do a normal select on the table with the same `TOP x` and the same `ORDER BY`, the last row retrieved should be the bad one. A simple bisection algorithm can be used to find `x`, ie. select top 1000, if this doesn't work, try 500 (half), then either 250 (half down) or 750 (half up from 500), depending on it fails or not, and so on.

Comment: @KMoussa True, I forget the replace! I tried again and there is 0 rows :(

Comment: @Maik maybe try checking if any of the resulting values has a length > 17

Comment: @KMoussa 0 rows if I add where len>16, so it is not length

Comment: @Maik since all else failed, you can cursor through the rows, do a cast and insert into a temp table, this can help narrow down the value that's failing at least

Comment: Oh It is true @KMoussa. It is a very good idea, thank you. I will try it and I will post what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using 2012 then you can use Try_Convert()

However there is a way to get this to work with 2008 by using a CASE statement. This works because CASE stops evaluating when it finds a match.

Here's a simple example for Varchar to Int but you can easily adapt it for Decimal.

```
CASE WHEN [value] LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN [value]
ELSE Convert(varchar(20), CAST([value] as INT))
END
```

Comment: I changed the as Int for the decimal conversion but the select returns all the rows without problem :S